# Remove many instances of the same character (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, user-input

When people are posting some text on my website, they will sometimes insert a long line of hyphens, asterisks or full-stops like this

```
*********************************************************************
```

That will unfortunately destroy the layout on some result pages, and it's kind of pointless (to me).

How should I handle this? Maybe a regex that will reduce more than X repeats of the same character to only 5. If so, then how...

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[\\*\\._-]{5,}");
string goodstring = regex.Replace(badstring, "-----");
```

But what if a user thought it was fun to write aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, then my regex would fail.

The question is. How do you think I should handle this problem and if you think I should handle it with a regex, then how do I write a regex that would remove unnecessary repeats of any character (and not just *.-_ like my own regex here)?

Comment: I would say reconsider your design so that it not breaks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your regular expression question:

> how do I write a regex that would remove unnecessary repeats of any character

You can use a backreference to detect the same character entered more than once, for example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.)\1{4,}");
```

---

However the main point of your question seems to be this:

> That will unfortunately destroy the layout on some result pages, and it's kind of pointless (to me). How should I handle this?

You should use stylesheets to specify what should happen when the text doesn't fit into its container. For example, you can use the [overflow property](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) to set the content to hide or scroll on overflow, rather than having the default behaviour which is that overflowing content can overlap other elements on the page.

Comment: This has fixed my problem. When printing out the posts:
`Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.)\1{4,}");
 p.Description = regex.Replace(p.Description, " ");
 p.Description = p.Description.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");`

Comment: I can't use overflow because it is on a div fixed in the middle of some other stuff, so scrollbars would just look horrible and hidden text would be a bit strange. But, thanks for the regex :)

Answer (score 2):

how to handle this is somewhat up to you/your client ... we can only advise but not answer on this ... I would (if you check for injects) just print whatever the user wants but chop/break it so it cannot destroy your layout - if you filter out multiples of one character (someone has put in there to *destroy* your layout) he/she will simple go on and write "abababababababababa" the next time and you are back on start

Comment: That is true. Something like sldjflsdjflsdkjldkjlfsjfkldfkj would go right through any regex of this type, so I guess I have to check word length also

Comment: no use either - you can always sprinkle with spaces or just copy a big-huge text or whatever... just make sure your layout can handle those big words/texts .. as I said - just crop them